# multiclass text classification

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, lstm

Why my `lstm` model is getting better accuracy than my bi `lstm` model? (multi-class text classification with 5 classes using word2vec and `lstm`) I tried to find the answer in any paper but I can't find it, almost all the paper said `bilstm` can improve the accuracy, can someone explain and give the references? Thanks

This is for 5 classes using `lstm`

```
Epoch 45/50
205/205 [==============================] - 284s 1s/step - loss: 0.6703 - accuracy: 0.7712 - val_loss: 0.9680 - val_accuracy: 0.6946
Epoch 46/50
205/205 [==============================] - 286s 1s/step - loss: 0.6571 - accuracy: 0.7709 - val_loss: 0.9682 - val_accuracy: 0.6937
Epoch 47/50
205/205 [==============================] - 282s 1s/step - loss: 0.6682 - accuracy: 0.7687 - val_loss: 0.9707 - val_accuracy: 0.6995
Epoch 48/50
205/205 [==============================] - 292s 1s/step - loss: 0.6658 - accuracy: 0.7681 - val_loss: 0.9847 - val_accuracy: 0.6961
Epoch 49/50
205/205 [==============================] - 288s 1s/step - loss: 0.6650 - accuracy: 0.7658 - val_loss: 0.9901 - val_accuracy: 0.6961
Epoch 50/50
205/205 [==============================] - 279s 1s/step - loss: 0.6629 - accuracy: 0.7711 - val_loss: 0.9821 - val_accuracy: 0.6921

this is for 5 classes using bilstm
Epoch 45/50
205/205 [==============================] - 313s 2s/step - loss: 0.6071 - accuracy: 0.7859 - val_loss: 0.9831 - val_accuracy: 0.7025
Epoch 46/50
205/205 [==============================] - 310s 2s/step - loss: 0.5971 - accuracy: 0.8002 - val_loss: 0.9834 - val_accuracy: 0.6888
Epoch 47/50
205/205 [==============================] - 316s 2s/step - loss: 0.5976 - accuracy: 0.7966 - val_loss: 1.0056 - val_accuracy: 0.6989
Epoch 48/50
205/205 [==============================] - 346s 2s/step - loss: 0.5858 - accuracy: 0.8020 - val_loss: 0.9978 - val_accuracy: 0.6964
Epoch 49/50
205/205 [==============================] - 322s 2s/step - loss: 0.5941 - accuracy: 0.7977 - val_loss: 1.0099 - val_accuracy: 0.6912
Epoch 50/50
205/205 [==============================] - 327s 2s/step - loss: 0.5886 - accuracy: 0.7987 - val_loss: 1.0049 - val_accuracy: 0.6986
```